# Where can I find the Transaction ID field (GA4) in Google Data Studio?

Tags: field, looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I can't seem to find the Transaction ID field from GA4 in my Google Data Studio. I need to use this field for a filter.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some field are not automatically added to the connector. I think you have to define it as a custom dimension using the property transaction_id. Then refresh the fields in your data source.